# Why is [] == ![] true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [];
Boolean(arr) // true
Boolean(!arr) // false
arr == arr // true
arr == !arr // true ??? what ???
```

I do not want to get the answer that 'recommend using `===` instead of `==`'.
I would like to know the reason for this phenomenon and the principle of type conversion of JavaScript.

Comment: I believe it is because `[]` is falsy (try `[] == 0`), but `!arr` becomes `!Boolean(arr)` which gives `!true` or `false`. The `==` operator probably doesn't call `Boolean()` on the left `arr`, since it knows to treat an empty list as falsy.

Comment: I can not agree. empty array is 'true', not 'false'

Comment: Also fun to realise: `[] == []` is false.

Comment: @msm082919 EmandM's answer below also suggests `[]` evaluates to false.

Comment: @DillonDavis: It suggested that incorrectly. `[]` is truthy.

Comment: Your assumption is that the arrays are compared as Booleans, which is not the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type conversion in JS, particularly with regards to loose equality, is a tricky beast.

The best place to always start when answering the question "why does this particular loose equality evaluate this way" is to consult [this table of equality comparisons by operand type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using).

In this case, we can see that for `[] == false`, Operand A is an Object and Operand B is a Boolean, so the actual comparison performed is going to be `ToPrimitive(A) == ToNumber(B)`.

The right side of that is simple; `ToNumber(false)` evaluates to `0`. Done and done.

The left side is more complex; you can check [the official ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) for full documentation of `ToPrimitive`, but all you really need to know is that in this case it boils down to `A.valueOf().toString()`, which in the case of the empty array is simply the empty string `""`

So, we end up evaluating the equality `"" == 0`. A String/Number `==` comparison performs `ToNumber` on the string, and `ToNumber("")` is `0`, so we get `0 == 0`, which is of course `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Double equals, `==`, performs an amount of type coercion on values before attempting to check for equality.

So `arr == arr` returns true as you'd expect as what you are actually checking is if `[] == []` and both sides of the equation are of the same type.

`arr == !arr` is actually checking if `[] == false`. The `==` then performs type coercion on the `[]` value. This does not, as Hamms pointed out, perform a *boolean* conversion, instead `[]` is turned into a primitive, which is an empty string due to reasons. So now our equation is `'' == false`. The types on the two sides of this operation are still not the same. So the type coercion kicks in again, and due to truthy and falsey values in javascript, `''` also evaluates to false. The equation now becomes `false == false`, which is obviously true.

Comment: why `[] also evaluates to false`? If this statement is correct why `Boolean([])` returns true

Comment: if ( [ ] ) { //this code run }.   why `[ ] == false // true`?

Comment: That's not quite accurate; you're right in that the case boils down to checking `[] == false`, but in this case JS will actually convert the first operand to its `ToPrimitive` value, not its `ToBoolean` value, and the primitive of an empty array is actually the empty _string_

Comment: The newly edited “truthy and falsy” part is still wrong – string == boolean doesn’t use truthiness of the string, but instead compares them numerically. Try `'x' == true`, or `'0' == false`.

Comment: Cheers for the pointers, Hamms answer is a much more complete answer than this one.